# How to display a view in the first time the app is opened?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

How can I display some view in the first time the app is opened like an instructions/tutorial page? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps have a bool value in `NSUserDefaults` to let you know whether or not the user's been through the tutorial yet. For example you can set:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"tutorial_complete"];
```

once the tutorial's complete. So:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"tutorial_complete"])
```

you can go to a tutorial page, but

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"tutorial_complete"])
```

you can skip the tutorial.

Comment: I tried the same way. But I'm having the problem that the view showing when I remove the instance of the app and use again.

Comment: @Ramakrishna Yes, if you delete the app, all the data you save to the app will be deleted as well. If you want to save the data, you'd have to post it to a server or cloud.

Comment: Thanks for u r replay. I got the solution.